# How to handle nested arrays in PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have a data in array format like this :

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Domain] => domain1.com
                        [Available] => true
                        [ErrorNo] => 0
                        [Description] => 
                        [IsPremiumName] => false
                        [PremiumRegistrationPrice] => 0
                        [PremiumRenewalPrice] => 0
                        [PremiumRestorePrice] => 0
                        [PremiumTransferPrice] => 0
                        [IcannFee] => 0
                        [EapFee] => 0
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Domain] => domain2.com
                        [Available] => true
                        [ErrorNo] => 0
                        [Description] => 
                        [IsPremiumName] => false
                        [PremiumRegistrationPrice] => 0
                        [PremiumRenewalPrice] => 0
                        [PremiumRestorePrice] => 0
                        [PremiumTransferPrice] => 0
                        [IcannFee] => 0
                        [EapFee] => 0
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Domain] => domain3.com
                        [Available] => true
                        [ErrorNo] => 0
                        [Description] => 
                        [IsPremiumName] => false
                        [PremiumRegistrationPrice] => 0
                        [PremiumRenewalPrice] => 0
                        [PremiumRestorePrice] => 0
                        [PremiumTransferPrice] => 0
                        [IcannFee] => 0
                        [EapFee] => 0
                    )

            )
)
```

I want to use this data on my blade view in Laravel.
So I did this :

```
@foreach($results as $result => $datas)
                        @foreach($datas as $data => $attributes )
                            @foreach($attributes as $attribute => $value)
                                <tr>
                                    @foreach($attribute["Domain"] as $domain)
                                    <td>{{ $domain }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <td>.COM</td>
                                    <td>.NET</td>
                                    <td>.ORG</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
```

But when I use it like : `{{ $attribute['Domain'] }}` it says :

> illegal string offset ...

And when I use it like : `{{ $attribute->Domain }}` it says

> Trying to get property of non-object ...

I don't know what else should I try! please help me. thanks.
P.S: I know , It's not necessary to use four foreachs here. There should be a better way to do this.

Comment: `$attribute` is a key. It can't be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$results` is a  provided array, then you can simplify your code to:

```
@foreach($results as $result)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $result['@attributes']['Domain'] }}</td>
        <td>.COM</td>
        <td>.NET</td>
        <td>.ORG</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```